# Select não exibe dados na listview

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

Não consigo obter retorno do meu select no banco. Onde eu mostro os dados em uma listview.

```
using (_connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("Database=roubo_furto; Data Source=192.168.0.17;User Id=RFID;Password=1234;SslMode=None;"))
            {
                System.Text.EncodingProvider ppp;
                ppp = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
                Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);

                _connection.Open();
               var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT distinct id, Carro, Placa, " +
      "Fabricante, Ano, Cor, Data FROM tcc " +
      "WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Data,'%d/%m/%Y') = STR_TO_DATE(" + txtDate.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + 
      ", '%d/%m/%Y')", _connection);

                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())


                        listView.Items.Add("Ocorrencia: Nº " + reader.GetString(0) + "    " + "\nData: " + Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetString(7)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "    " + "\nCarro: " + reader.GetString(2) + "    " + "\nPlaca: " + reader.GetString(3) + "    " + "\nCor: " + reader.GetString(6) + "    " + "\nAno: " + reader.GetString(5) + "    " + "\nFabricante: " + reader.GetString(4) + "\n\n");


                }
            }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
        <DatePicker x:Name="txtDate" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,208,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="415" ToolTipService.ToolTip="" MonthFormat="{}{month.solo.full}">
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Adiciona todo o código, por gentileza, incluindo a parte onde voce atribui os dados pro reader. Mas, se você estiver atribuindo certinho, eu testaria: reader["id"], reader["Data"]...

Comment: Adicionei mais informações

Comment: Utlize Paramenters ele faz toda conversão...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltam mais detalhes na questão, mais acredito que o problema pode ser com relação ao formato da data que está configurado no sistema, já tive muitos problemas com isso, de estar configurado com um padrão de formato de data na maquina do cliente e o mysql utilizar outro padrão. Nestes casos o MYSQL não consegue encontrar os dados, porque ele converte o valor do campo data para string em um formato (por padrão é 'YYYY-MM-DD') e os dados do filtro estão em outro ('DD/MM/YYYY' por exemplo).

Existem duas maneiras de se resolver a questão, formatando o campo data e forçando a entrada de dados no mesmo formato ou utilizando parâmetros no meio do comando SQL e no Objeto MySqlCommand.

**Método 1, forçando o formato do campo de Data**

Você pode forçar o formato do campo Date com auxilio dos métodos STR_TO_DATE e DATE_FORMAT. Abaixo um exemplo de como deveria ficar forçando um formato 'DD/MM/YYYY'.

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT distinct id, Carro, Placa, " +
          "Fabricante, Ano, Cor, Data FROM tcc " +
          "WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Data,'%d/%m/%Y') = STR_TO_DATE(" + txtDate.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + 
          ", '%d/%m/%Y')", _connection);
```

Veja mais detalhes na documentação do método str_to_date:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date
e sobre DATE_FORMAT:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

**Método 2, utilizando parâmetros**

Basta utilizar Parametros no MySQLCommand:

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT distinct id, Carro, Placa, " +
          "Fabricante, Ano, Cor, Data FROM tcc " +
          "WHERE Data = @dataParametro", _connection);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataParametro", txtDate.Date);
```

Seria ideal você verificar como os dados estão gravados no banco de dados, pois se os dados estiverem sendo gravados no banco como `DateTime` (Data com hora). Para que o comando funcione o conteúdo do componente `txtDate` deve conter o mesmo valor (incluindo `hh:mm:ss`) que a linha do banco de dados.

Comment: Não deu muito certo ou não entendi direito

Comment: Se for utlizado o Parameters não precisa converte nada, isso eu vejo muitos errando.

Comment: Tem como explicar melhor?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com mais alguns detalhes e um exemplo de utilização de parametros.

Comment: Esta dando uma mensagem de ero agora

Comment: Vou editar novamente, provavelmente no seu banco vc está gravando data e hora no campo Data e quando vai fazer a comparação não consegue comparar porque os formatos de data são muito diferentes.

Comment: @Jon, utilize o primeiro método como descrito na minha resposta, deve funcionar agora.

Comment: @Julio com Erro. Menssagem na edição da pergunta